# Visual Studio 2015/17 - Visual C++ Adding a reference to a project references the target/output library instead of a project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

this might actually be a stupid question as I don't get the internals of VS and so I might miss something.

**What I am trying to do** (simplified version).
I have basically 3 projects A, B and C (vcxproj files) in different locations. Then I use these projects in two solutions that are in other places (Say S1 and S2 and more details about the structure to come...). To make things work I had to use a lot $(ProjectDir) instead of $(SolutionDir) to identify locations. This way I can reuse the projects in S1 and S2 making sure that if I do $(ProjectDir)....\ to reference something (.h .lib or other files) they are in the correct location.
Now say in S1 I have imported A, B and C where B and C depend on A and so I added a reference in B and C to A. All good so far but...

**What goes wrong**
1) If look at the properties of reference to A in B (in S1) I can see that the "Full path" points at the library file produced by A not to A.vcxproj file 
2) Although this is incidentally right in one S1 (when I say right I mean that it points to something that is actually produced and available) when I get to S2 the library coming from project A that it points to it's in a wrong location (still I was expecting to reference the project and not the output lib)

**Questions**
1) Does anybody know why a reference to a project has the full path that points to a library?
2) Even if that is correct because when you are adding a dependency you are actually say that you depend on the product of it, why do they point a different path in the two different solutions? Maybe even using $(ProjectDir) to make paths depending on the project and not the solution is not enough...

Thanks to you all

Comment: You are no longer in C# land.  The add reference feature in C++ is a simple way to tell the *linker* that it needs to also link the .lib file produced by the project.  The linker knows beans about a .vcxproj file, it needs the .lib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added the reference via `References -> Add Reference...` then you should see a `ProjectReference` element in your `.vcxproj` file. As you can probably see, the `Include` attribute references the project and not the output.

The reason why your paths are different between solutions is probably because you have the `Project Properties -> General -> Output Directory` of project `A` set to  use `$(SolutionDir)` variable and that implies the `Full Path` changes when if solution `S1` is in a different directory than `S2`.

You can change your output directory to be independent of the `$(SolutionDir)`, e.g. `C:\Build\$(Configuration)` to have the same `Full Path` for both solutions when using the same `$(Configuration)` (e.g. `Debug`).

You may need to reload projects that reference project `A` if your change the `Output Directory` of the project to see the updated `Full Path`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Marcin Zawiejski. So yes you are right about looking at the reference in the project file, it points to a project file and not to a library or output file... what was actually confusing me is that I have updated the $(SolutionDir) to $(ProjectDir), but I didn't updated/reload the projects. Actually what I think worked was to remove all the references and re-adding them again.